# Bloquear download em um streaming de audio

Tags: c#, mvc

Tenho uma aplicação Web MVC na qual retoma um stream de áudio de acordo com os parâmetros recebido:

```
public new ActionResult File(string q, string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var query = new GetFileQuery()
            {
                q = q.Substring(0, 8),
                sequencial = q.Substring(8),
                path = url
            };

            if (query.q == query.Hash1)
            {
                string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(query.fileName);

                var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                {
                    FileName = query.fileName,
                    Inline = true,
                };

                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

                query.ConvertWavMP3(query.path);

                 File(
                    query.fileBytes
                    , contentType);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Porém necessito que este áudio seja apenas para visualização sem a opção de download e o mesmo esteja em uma *tag audio*, como chamo esse arquivo na *tag* e bloqueio a opção de download?

Comment: O que quer dizer com "apenas para visualização" ?

Comment: Seria sem a opção de fazer o download apenas stream assim como o youtube com os videos.

Comment: seu código está mais para download mesmo do que stream.. de uma olhada nesse link que vai ter ajudar: [transmitindo-audio-e-video](http://codingfirst.blogspot.com/2013/02/transmitindo-audio-e-video.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para remove a opção de download da tag áudio você pode usar `controlsList="nodownload"` vê [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controlsList). Porém isso não garante que o download seja feito.

```html
<div id="player">
  <audio id="audio" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Fur_Elise.ogg" controls controlsList="nodownload"></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Sensacional! Mas, como implemento para que o controle insira o caminho do áudio para essa tag ? Tenho que criar uma view?

Comment: Isso. Porém, se você quiser fazer um stream de áudio terá que fazer em web api. Segue um tutorial: https://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/. O que você pode fazer é trazer o seu aquivo de áudio ou a url dele onde está hospedado e inserir na tag audio:

<audio id="audio" src="@model.urlAudio" controls controlsList="nodownload"></audio>

Comment: Cara eu não consigo colocar no src o caminho do audio no servidor ?